# Running a sample stored procedure with error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please help.

I am trying to create a procedure similar to this code:

```
 DECLARE @OldPK AS VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @PK AS VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @S AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @P AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @PK = 'ModeName'
 SET @S = N'SELECT @pOldPK = @pPK FROM Modes '
 SET @P = N'@pPK VARCHAR(50), @pOldPK VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT'
 EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @S, @P, @pPK = @PK, @pOldPK = @OldPK OUTPUT
 SELECT @OldPK
```

When I try to debug and after the line

```
 EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @S, @P, @pPK = @PK, @pOldPK = @OldPK OUTPUT
```

it stops and generates an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Your valuable inputs is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you executing this code? Within SQL Management Studio? From code?

Comment: within SSMS, thanks n8wrl

Comment: Does everything else work in SSMS? That sounds to me like something wrong with the installation...

Comment: The SQL is also quite strange, you're assigning a value from a variable to another, but using a table for it, and there's no where clause either...

Comment: Didn't experience any problem during installation (SQL Server 2012 - standard edition), is there a way to check if I have an existing problem?  thanks JamesZ

Comment: That query doesn't make much sense and why are you using dynamic sql here?

Comment: So this is a totally new installation? Sounds like something went wrong there, unfortunately I have no other ideas than try to reinstall / repair (if repair even exists)

Comment: I am trying to come-up with a code for auditing data using (dynamic columns) in which the stored procedure will be called by a trigger.  thanks Sean Lange

Comment: This looks wrong in a few ways.   Where is pPK declared?   Don't you need to concatenate at least one of those variables when building your dynamic string?

Comment: I might not sure if I declared it correctly but I did however declared it in the parameter @P.  Thanks - Tab Alleman

Comment: I solved the issue in the codes by rectifying the Line 11 however it still doesn't give me what I want in regard to dynamically assign a column.  Don't know how to re-post the codes.   thanks.

Comment: You can either edit this question, or close it and create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try now, your column name is being treated as a literal string the way you were trying to do it.

```
DECLARE @OldPK AS VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @PK AS VARCHAR(50)
 DECLARE @S AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @P AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @PK = 'ModeName'
 SET @S = N'SELECT TOP 1 @pOldPK = ' + QUOTENAME(@pPK) + ' FROM Modes '
 SET @P = N'@pOldPK VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT'
 EXECUTE dbo.sp_executesql @S
                         , @P
                         , @pOldPK = @OldPK OUTPUT
 SELECT @OldPK
```

Comment: Thanks @M.Ali.  However this doesn't give the results that I want to generate the corresponding record of the given dynamic column.  This gives me results with NULL value

Comment: Are you sure there are no null values in that column? if there nulls then just add a where clause something like where column is not null etc

Comment: Thanks.  I only have one record in my sample table